# Default headers for HTTP requests - Android

Tags: android, http, http-headers

I was wondering what *default headers* or data is sent to a server when `HTTP requests` are made from an `Android device`. I mean even after disabling any kind of data sharing over `HTTP` this information is always shared to an end point.

This information might contain device make, `user-agent/browser info`, app info if `HTTP` requests are made using an app.

*What all details I **always** get at server side for simple `HTTP` calls made from an Android device (ignoring the modes of making these HTTP calls)*?

Comment: Is the app using webview, `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, or any HTTP Client library like `OkHttp`?. It depends on the HTTP client being used. For plain request using `HttpURLConnection`, there's no HTTP headers.

Comment: @PhilipBorbon It could be any mode of making Http requests...I am looking for any kind of data that tells me what device has made a request, user agent etc. Not much idea about Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as having default headers. You cannot expect that Android catches all outgoing requests at OS level and adds his own headers, this would be a serious issue and a restriction for users and developers. Also this apply to every OS, not only Android.

Your best bet is to base on the user-agent: it contains the word "Android" which is the main way to discern an Android client and usually the OS version and device model.

Most apps use the user-agent returned by WebView, which is a component that can be used to display web pages inside the app and contains the same user-agent that the standard Android browser is adding in the stand-alone app.
But I repeat that it is entirely to the developer.

An Android user-agent example related to Samsung Galaxy S9

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G960F Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is possible to alter user-agent so that cannot be trusted. I was looking for **some** information which can actually help me distinguish HTTP requests made from different devices. I cannot use IPs for that purpose as they change when connected to different wi-fi networks. Now these HTTP requests can be made from a browser or some app as well.